# Angularjs UI-Grid: Display Elements in Array from an Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I am having an issue trying to figure out how to get an object with an array to populate a grid column. Example

```
var myArrayOfObjects = [{
   foo: "bar"
   myArray: [{ foo: "bar" }, { bar: "foo" }]
}]
```

myObject.myArray is in fact an array with a couple of objects. Here is how I am defining my gridOptions:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,
    columnDefs: [
        { name: 'bar', field: 'foo', width: '15%' }
        { name: 'foobars', field: 'myArray', width: '15%'},
    ],
    data: myObject
};
```

I have defined a column to map to the field 'myArray' but this does not work. The above just displays the string of the entire array. If I specific an index of the the array like so, myArray[0].foo the string "bar" will appear. I want to display both object and their respect info without specifying the index. Just like how myArrayOfObjects populated the grid, I want to have the array inside the object to populate that one column. Any help would be most appreciated!!!

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/XuIu5X?p=preview)?

Comment: @IanA Your plunker link is broken. can you repost it?

Comment: I think it's the Plunkr website. I get the message "Unable to connect to any application instances" even when going to [http://plnkr.co/](http://plnkr.co/)

Comment: Yeah seeing the same thing. Seems like plunkr is temporarily down lol

Comment: @JoesphFreeman Looks like Plunker is back up now